# Why can't Python execute java.exe via subprocess?

Tags: java, python, windows, subprocess

After upgrading Java from 1.6 to 1.7 x64 (on Windows 7), I suddenly can't launch java.exe via Python 2.7's `subprocess` module anymore. The following script used to just work:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call([r"C:\Windows\system32\java.exe"])
```

Now it fails like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tst.py", line 2, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call([r"C:\Windows\system32\java.exe"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 506, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have also confirmed that `C:\Windows\system32\java.exe` does indeed exist, is an application, and can be executed from the command shell.

What goes wrong here?

**EDIT:**
I've found that I can start `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe` from Python, so  `C:\Windows\system32\java.exe` must be some weird pseudo-shortcut although technically a Windows application. Version 1.7 must've messed it up somehow, since I just confirmed Version 1.6 is fine.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a link?

Comment: @Marcin According to the file properties the file type is `Application (.exe)`.

Comment: If you can investigate a bit more, your edit would make a great answer. If you can't investigate more, consider adding it as an answer anyway.

Comment: @Marcin Gonna submit feedback to Java developers, hopefully they'll get back to me.

Comment: Running fsutil, it is not a hardlink

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that there is a java.exe at "C:\Windows\System32" is not a particularly safe assumption. Even the assumption there is a "C:\Windows\System32" on the system isn't safe:  Windows could reside on *any* fixed drive on the computer.

But even if there is a "C:\Windows\System32\java.exe", this might not be visible for 32-bit processes under Win64. Windows does some interesting things here in the name of backwards compatibility, you might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64.

Finding the Java version you're looking for - and there can be many - can be a thankless task. If you don't particularly care about *which* Java you find, try the JAVA_HOME environment variable. It's not always there, but if it is, you're done and it's probably the most portable way of finding a JVM. If it's not there, you can't go wrong by setting it, and many Java applications can make use of that variable.

Then again, Java just *might* be on the PATH, in which case *removing* the everything but 'java' in the subprocess call will do the trick. It can't hurt to try.

Comment: The reason C:\Windows\system32\java.exe was relevant to me is that it is how I usually find java.exe via `PATH`, I don't directly rely on that executable path. But you may well be onto something regarding WoW64, I will investigate, thanks.

Comment: You were onto something. `False` is printed when executing the following with 32-bit Python, but `True` for 64-bit Python: `python.exe -c "import os.path; print os.path.exists(r'C:\windows\system32\java.exe')"`. Apparently 32-bit apps on 64-bit Windows are redirected from C:\Windows\System32 to C:\Windows\SysWOW64,  where there is no java.exe.

Comment: Why isn't this one of the top voted of all time answers on SO?

Comment: I also hit this bug. For me, directly using path "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" worked (64-bit, 1.7.0_67-b01). Using just "java" (from the PATH) returned no output even if I issued a legitimate command with subprocess.check_output(...)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check if the PATH environment variable has quotation marks "" around the jre's bin path. Python doesn't seem to like them:

```
    C:\bin>set PATH=C:\Python27;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin

    C:\bin>python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)"

    C:\bin>set PATH=C:\Python27;"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin"

    C:\bin>python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
    WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    C:\bin>
```